# Count keywords occurrence in a file to another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files File1 and File2. I have to find keywords in File2 to File1 and count it. Lines in File1 that don't have any keywords in File2 shall be counted as OTHERS and probably save it in File3 (for validation).

File1

```
 000001111YYYY0000
 122334YYYY9999
 89898989AAAA89899
 AAAA7678989812234
 ZZZZ878098098098
 0000000000000000
```

File2

```
YYYY
AAAA
ZZZZ
```

Output

```
YYYY: 2
AAAA: 2
ZZZZ: 1
OTHERS: 1
```

File3 (OTHERS)

```
0000000000000000
```

The way I know is to count the keywords using grep and wc -l, and its not ideal especially when I have many keywords to find.

Comment: Show your attempts

Comment: What should the result be for a value in file2 that doesn't appear in file1 - output with a zero count or not output at all?

Comment: could be there lines in `File1` with multiple keywords per line like `ZZZZ01111YYYY0000` ? How should they be considered?

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

CMDLINE

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}\
{b=1;for(i in a)if(z=gsub(i,"&")){x[i]+=z;b=0}}\
b{x["Others"]++;print > "file3"}\
END{for(i in x)print i, x[i]}' file{2,}
```

Or probably more suited to a script due to length

```
FNR==NR{
    Strings[$1]
    next
}
{
    Found=0
    for(Regex in Strings)
        if(matches=gsub(Regex,"&")){
            Sums[Regex]+=matches
            Found=1
        }
}
!Found{
    Sums["Others"]++ 
    print > "file3"
}
END{
     for(Regex in Sums)
         print Regex, Sums[Regex]
}
```

Save as

```
awkscript.awk
```

Run as

```
awk -f awkscript.awk file{2,}
```

Comment: @EdMorton I understand where you are coming from and I considered that but thought it made the following code block easier to interpret, as it is run if there is no match. If there was a reason somewhere else to negate the var i would have just used `Match`. Regarding the strings I will update to make clearer.

Comment: @EdMorton Since it is a  (NoMatch) condition that is being checked for explicitly i.e that there are no matches,and isn't used for anything else then I personally think it is okay, but I have updated anyway.

Comment: People don't just have to read and understand where variables are tested to understand your code though, they have to do the same where the variables are set. The meaning of `found=true` is immediately obvious while `NoMatch=false`, since it's a double-negative, requires a pause to figure out what the condition is it really represents.

Answer (score 0):

try: If you are not bothering about the sequence of the output as per file1 or file2 then following may help you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$0];next} {gsub(/[0-9]/,"");} ($0 in A){B[$0]++;next} !($0 in A) && $0{OTHERS[$0]++} END{for(i in B){print i": "B[i]};for(j in OTHERS){print j": "OTHERS[j]}}' file2  file1
```

Will add description shortly too.

**EDIT1:** Adding code in non-one liner form and with proper explanation too here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{                                                 #### FNR==NR condition will be TRUE when first file file2 is being read, FNR and NR are awks built-in variables, both re-present line numbers of files only difference between them is FNR gets re-set whenever a new file is getting started and NRs value will be keep on increasing till all files get read.
                A[$0];                                        #### creating an array whose index is $0(current line) of file2.
                next                                          #### using next keyword for skipping all the next statements.
            }
            {
                VAL=$0;                                       #### creating a variable named VAL which has current lines value.
                gsub(/[0-9]/,"");                             #### gsub is awks built-in function to globally substituting all the digits to NULL in lines for file1.
            }
     ($0 in A){                                               #### now checking if new-edited $0(current line) is present in array A then do following statements.
                B[$0]++;                                      #### creating an array named B with index of $0 and incrementing its value with 1 each time.
                next                                          #### using next keyword for skipping all the next statements.
              }
     !($0 in A){                                              #### If current line is NOT present in array A.
                        OTHERS[VAL]++                         #### create an array named OTHERS with index of variable VAL and increment its value with 1 each time it comes in this section.
                     }
     END{                                                     #### Starting END section here for awk.
                for(i in B){                                  #### Traversing through array B now.
                                print i": "B[i]               #### printing the index of array B and its respective value now.
                           };
                for(j in OTHERS){                             #### Traversing through array OTHERS now.
                                        print j": "OTHERS[j]  #### printing index of array B with its value too.
                                }
        }
    ' file2  file1                                            #### Mentioning the Input_files now.
```

Comment: Removing all the digits means that the `000...` line will not be in others.

Comment: @123: I have overlooked it, I edited my answer now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution (including saving "others" into separate file `file3.txt`):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ group=(group)?group"|"$0 : $0; next }
     { if(match($0,group)){ a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++ } 
       else { a["OTHERS"]++; print >> "file3.txt" } 
     } END { for(i in a) print i": "a[i] }' file2 file1
```

The output:

```
ZZZZ: 1
AAAA: 2
YYYY: 2
OTHERS: 1
```

---

*Others*:

```
cat file3.txt
0000000000000000
```

Comment: That would only match one file2 value per line of file1.

Comment: @EdMorton. let's ask the OP about that moment

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{a["OTHERS"]=0}
  (NR==FNR) {a[$0]=0;next}
  {b=0}{for(i in a) if( match($0,i) !=0 ){a[i]++;b=1} }
  {if(b==0) a["OTHERS"]++} 
  END{for(i in a) print i,": ",a[i]}' 
  File2 File1
```